# Minimum amount of dirt required for covering blood

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, slaughter-shochet-shecht, yoreh-deah, kisui-hadam

Halacha mandates when Jews do shechita of chickens and wild animals they cover their blood with dirt. The question I have is what the minimum amount of dirt is necessary to use to fullfill this mitzvah of kisui hadam?

Comment: Presumably, very little. If there’s no blood left (it mixed with water or something) then you can just cover the blood on the knife which is minimal.